# How do I send an email from a form?

Tags: html, email, button, submit

This is what my code looks like and I can't get it to send to my email and I don't know how to do it?

```
<form id="contacts-form" action="">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="field">
      <label>Your Name:</label>
      <input type="text" value=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <label>Your E-mail:</label>
      <input type="email" value=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <label>Your Website:</label>
      <input type="text" value=""/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Your Message:</label>
      <textarea cols="1" rows="1"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="alignright">
      <a href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('contacts-form').submit()">
        Send Your Message!
      </a>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: There is no E-Mail sending code in what you show. You're missing the important part

Comment: @AndroidHustle, your comment sounds rude and is not very constructive or encouraging the other guy to explain his problem.

Comment: Assuming you are using PHP, perhaps start here: http://swiftmailer.org/ Hint: HTML does not send email by itself.

Comment: @wesley just out of curiosity, he can change the action to a `mailto:` protocol and set up JS to some how serialise and attach that form data to that mail to protocol, which will launch your default MUA like outlook or thunderbird or evolution, don't think this is an answer but I guess its possible, I will try it though

Comment: @Kumar: It will work with `action="mailto:"` (no js required), but I don't think it's cross browser. You may get an email with a subject line like "Form Post From Mozilla". I don't recommend it and I don't think we should teach it.

Comment: @Wesley, even I wont recommend this but was wondering if it is possible, thanks for commenting :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need a back-end that will send the email and you need to tell your form where to send its information. [Try this tutorial](http://www.phpjabbers.com/make-contact-form-and-send-email-in-php-php21.html) (which uses php) to learn how to do it. There will be plenty of tutorials in other languages, but you can't do this with html alone.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do some server side coding.  Here is a link to a page I found http://www.perlfect.com/articles/sendmail.shtml on how to do it using Perl.  But pick your favorite programming language and you will find examples on how to send code.

Whatever you code it in the action in our form will point to the script that will accept the fields and send the email.